# Override global variable inside function not working with Spyder 4

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

I try to override globally defined Dataframes from within a function. 
Somehow the global values do not change, printing the dataframes within the functions works with the expected values.

```
import pandas as pd

rawData = pd.read_csv("music.csv")
appTitles =pd.DataFrame #also with pd.DataFrame() wont get affected

def loadTitles(df=rawData):
    global appTitles
    appTitles = pd.DataFrame({'Title' : df['title']})
    print(appTitles) 
return appTitles #(second 'print' to screen)

#RUN FILE
#CALL FUNCTION: loadTitles() #-> No Variable appTitles
```

The appTitles variable in the variable explorer remains empty or nonexistent (depending use of pd.DataFrame/pd.DataFrame()) Thank you!

**EDIT:** After @4turkuaz commented that on his environment everthing works as expected, I tried Python console within Windows cmd and also on Spyder3 with Python 3.7.4 & IPython 7.8.0 where also everything worked fine.

Only on Spyder4 with Python 3.7.5 & IPython 7.10.1 it won't work. Maybe a bug? I don't know...

**EDIT:** Downgrading Spyder4 to Python 3.7.4 & IPython 7.8.0 did not solve the problem. I'm assuming that something within Spyder4 or the Anaconca Environment even though I installed it over and over is not correct.

Comment: Well actually, it worked as you expected on my environment with Python 3.6.

Comment: I'm on 3.7 using Spyder as IDE

Comment: Can you downgrade it to 3.6 and try again?

Comment: Just tried within python console on windows and it works as expected. Weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to go to the menu

`Run > Configuration per file`

and activate the option called `Run in console's namespace instead of an empty one`, for you to be able to modify global variables in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much, after activating the option it works now as planned but even if I uncheck it again. I don't know if this is the wanted behaviour.

Comment: Does this not work with class functions? I'm setting my variable at the module level and everything, but there's nothing I can do to see the global variable when it's set within a class instance's function... :( I've always avoided using modular code in Spyder for this reason, but it would REALLY make maintainability of my projects much easier if I can still use the global view (best feature in Spyder and why I love it)

Comment: Ah, I was actually able to do this another way. For anyone else looking for a similar way of accessing class variables in Spyder's variable explorer (eg self.some_var), you can expose those member objects to the caller via `some_capture_var = vars(some_class)`! Works great, and you'll  be able to dive through `some_capture_var` to find all the nested member variables with their values, all the way down...